# SQL 3 table join where first two inner then outer

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have 3 tables: users, subscriptions, and premium_subscriptions

- **users** has id, first_name, last_name, etc
- **subscriptions** has id, user_id, magazine_id, etc
- **premium_subscriptions** has id, magazine_id, user_id

I want to get all the subscriptions to which a specified user belongs, and then tack on a final column which states whether or not (as in premium_subscription id or null) the user is a premium subscriber.

So I thought the first two tables would be a standard inner join on the user id. This gets all the rows I want, and then another join which keeps all the same rows but gets the premium_subcription id if the user has a relationship and null if it doesn't.

Is this possible with a single query?

Comment: I suggest you also look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you were pretty close, here's a working query:

```
SELECT u.first_name, 
       u.last_name, 
       s.magazine_id, 
       ps.id
  FROM users u 
  JOIN subscriptions s 
    ON u.id = s.user_id
  LEFT JOIN premium_subscriptions ps
    ON s.user_id = ps.user_id AND s.magazine_id = ps.magazine_id
```

And a SQL Fiddle if you want to play around with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5e58/6

Comment: Very thorough, with the helpful fiddle. Thanks! Unimportant tidbit is the getting the specified user which would add a where clause at the end u.id = [id]

Answer (score 1):

Sure that is possible, it is called a left join.

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
   JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.id=u.user_id
   LEFT JOIN premium_subscriptions AS p 
        ON p.user_id=s.user_id AND p.magazine_id=s.magazine_id
```

A left join will return NULL for every queried column of the joined table in case there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` and a `CASE` Statement.  Something like below should work:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.first_name, 
       u.last_name, 
       s.magazine_id, 
       CASE
       WHEN ps.id is null
       THEN 'No'
       ELSE 'Yes'
       END as Premium_Subscriber
FROM users u
INNER JOIN subscriptions s
ON u.id=s.user_id
LEFT JOIN premium_subscriptions ps
ON ps.id=u.id
AND ps.user_id=s.user_id
AND ps.magazine_id=s.magazine_id
```